# Displaying modules in a Prism region when available

Tags: .net, wpf, module, prism, mef

I want to load modules when my app loads and have them put their views in a [region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) (see also [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx)) in the Shell (the main view). I am currently loading a module on demand and it works just fine. (I load the module with a button that calls `this.moduleManager.LoadModule("ModuleB");` where `moduleManager` is defined as `[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)] private IModuleManager moduleManager;`. This all comes from the [ModularityWithMef.Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921068%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) sample application.) Here's the relevant code:

**Module**

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(ModuleB), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand)]
public class ModuleB : IModule
{
    [Import(AllowRecomposition = false)] private IRegionManager _regionManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ModuleB"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ModuleB()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the module that it has be initialized.
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.AddToRegion("ContentRegion", new ModuleBView());
    }
}
```

**XAML region**

```
<TabControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
```

When I change to loading the module when available (`[ModuleExport(typeof(ModuleB), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]`), I get a ModuleInitializeException when the bootstrapper is creating the Shell saying "This RegionManager does not contain a Region with the name 'ContentRegion'." This tells me that there is a timing issue with the creation of the region in the Shell and the initialization of the module.

So here's my question: **How do I register the module's view with the Shell's region upon discovery and without having to use OnDemand initialization and manually load the module?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this was an easy answer that was, for some reason, hard for me to find. The `IRegionManager` provides a `RegisterViewWithRegion` method that takes a function that returns the view. This allows the region manager to instantiate the view when it is ready (as opposed to using `AddToRegion`, which happens immediately). So the key is to use that method in the module's `Initialize` routine:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", () => new ModuleBView());
}
```

While I was figuring this out, I also came up with a workaround. When the module is set to `InitializationMode.OnDemand`, the Shell can import the `IModuleManager` and use `LoadModule` in the `ContentRendered` event. This ensures that the region has been added to the region manager and that the module can add its view without a problem. If you need to iterate through the available modules, use this event handler:

```
public Shell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ContentRendered += (o, eventArgs) =>
        {
            foreach (var moduleInfo in _moduleCatalog.Modules)
            {
                _moduleManager.LoadModule(moduleInfo.ModuleName);
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to merry Views and the Region in the bootstrapper, in the 
AggregateCatalog.Changed _handler - this is where you know that your module is already loaded and Shell is already instantiated with all the modules.